# How to batch start background tasks?

Tags: batch-jobs

I have such files:

```
ls
```

> `mate30pro5g.py  Mathematica.py  opencv.py`

I know this command can start a background task:

```
python3 mate30pro5g.py &
```

Now I want to start multiple tasks by this command:

```
ls *.py | xargs -n1 -i python3 {} &
```

But I find I launch only one background task.. What I have missed?

---

**ps:** note all my `.py` file have an endless loop..

Comment: `xargs` will not run commands in parallel, but one after the other. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357997/running-programs-in-parallel-using-xargs)

Comment: @Fiximan As your link, `ls *.py | xargs -n1 -P7 -i python3 {} &` is what I'm after?

Comment: Yes, `-P` should give you parallel processes. I am not sure about sending to background , though. `-P 0` will even allow any number of parallel processes, depending on number of arguments (and `-n` option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is `&` is interpreted by the calling shell , this is not transmit to xargs .

so you must call bash that will execute python3 with you args .

solution:

```
ls *.py | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'python3 {} &'
```

A example :

```
root@debian:/# ls -1d /etc/rc* | xargs -n1  -i bash -c  'sleep 90 & echo {} '
/etc/rc0.d
/etc/rc1.d
/etc/rc2.d
/etc/rc3.d
/etc/rc4.d
/etc/rc5.d
/etc/rc6.d
/etc/rcS.d
root@debian:/# ps faux | grep sleep
root       494  0.0  0.0   4184   704 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       496  0.0  0.0   4184   672 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       498  0.0  0.0   4184   652 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       500  0.0  0.0   4184   648 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       502  0.0  0.0   4184   672 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       504  0.0  0.0   4184   656 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       506  0.0  0.0   4184   648 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       508  0.0  0.0   4184   684 pts/0    S    20:54   0:00 sleep 90
root       510  0.0  0.0  11108   948 pts/0    S+   20:54   0:00 grep sleep
```

Another solution because you want to manage all yours process with jobs .
You need create a big string that contains all yours commands and call `eval` on it .

```
CMD=$( ls *py | xargs -n1  -i echo ' python3 {} & ' )
eval $CMD
```

or

```
eval $( ls *py | xargs -n1  -i echo ' python3 {} & ' )
```

Comment: Hello, it work for your? But when I use `jobs` to check, I have no any background task?

Comment: please check with `ps faux | grep python3`

Comment: updated with a example

Comment: Thanks for your solution, just don't ease to manage... I mean if we want to kill this process, we have to use `kill pid`. If there is not other better answer I will choice it.

Comment: updated with using eval

Comment: Crazy....man, I'm very very love your newest tirck. :)